# ValueError: expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to create a categorical vBar that will show the total number of migrants picked up for various operations, however, when I pass the 'groupby' pandas object into the column data source, I keep getting an error and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have looked in a few places for similar problems, but I can't seem to find any answers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
#Imports
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.layouts import row

#Global variables
viewFilter='Operation'

#Data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
grouped = df.groupby(viewFilter)['Total Migrants']
source = ColumnDataSource(grouped)
#grouped = df.groupby(viewFilter)['Total Migrants'].sum()
#source = ColumnDataSource(pd.DataFrame(grouped))
operations = source.data[viewFilter].tolist()

# Fig Creation Function 
def create_figure():
    global viewFilter
    p=figure(x_range=operations)
    p.vbar(x=viewFilter, top='Total Migrants', 
           source=source, width=0.70)

    p.title.text='Demo Chart'
    p.xaxis.axis_label = viewFilter
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Total Migrants'

    #Hover took
    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips=[
        ("Total Migrants Rescued", "@{Total Migrants}")]
    hover.mode='vline'
    p.add_tools(hover)

    return p

#Update Data with Ship-level aggregation
def shipUpdate():
    print("Ship Button was Pushed")

#Widgets
shipButton = Button(label='Ship Level')
shipButton.on_click(shipUpdate)

#Implement Layout
layout = row(shipButton, create_figure())

#Add Layout to Document
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving, please?

Comment: ValueError: expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if I explicitly pass in a pandas dataframe object, it solves this error:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(pd.DataFrame(grouped))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wrong parameter value has passed in groupby() method or in ColumnDataSource()

Syntax:

```
DataFrame.groupby(by=None, axis=0, level=None, as_index=True, sort=True, group_keys=True, squeeze=False, observed=False, **kwargs)
```

Parameter by-> list, str, dict

And the code snippet of the constructer of ColumnDataSource is below -

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        ''' If called with a single argument that is a dict or
        pandas.DataFrame, treat that implicitly as the "data" attribute.

        '''
        if len(args) == 1 and "data" not in kw:
            kw["data"] = args[0]

        # TODO (bev) invalid to pass args and "data", check and raise exception
        raw_data = kw.pop("data", {})

        if not isinstance(raw_data, dict):
            if pd and isinstance(raw_data, pd.DataFrame):
                raw_data = self._data_from_df(raw_data)
            elif pd and isinstance(raw_data, pd.core.groupby.GroupBy):
                raw_data = self._data_from_groupby(raw_data)
            else:
                raise ValueError("expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame, got %s" % raw_data)
        super(ColumnDataSource, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.data.update(raw_data)
```

Comment: Technically correct as @bigreddot said, instead of being a 'groupby' object, I was passing through the result of a 'sum'.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Bokeh is too old. Support for passing Pandas `GroupBy` objects was added in version 0.12.7. If you want to be able to pass `GroupBy` objects directly to initialize a CDS (e.g. to access all the automatic summary statistics that creates), you will need to upgrade to a newer release.

Comment: Currently running bokeh version 0.13.0

Comment: I actually just realize you are not passing a `GroupBy`. You are passing the result of `.sum` (which is the problem, CDS does not expect that). There is no need to do that, if you pass the `GroupBy` Bokeh will make summary statistics available automatically: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#pandas

Comment: Interestingly, when I changed that, it stopped being an error - but now it renders a blank page. But when I revert to the original (and incorrect workaround.) it renders as expected. Any ideas on what the cause might be, or do you think I should open a new question?

Comment: When you pass a `GroupBy`, Bokeh will automatically create columns in the CDS with the summary data, using a defined rule to name the columns. You will need to pass the right columns names to `vbar` etc as described in the docs I linked. You can also just look at the keys in `source.data` to see the column names.